# bindkey commands run in .zshrc seem ignored when in tmux

Tags: zsh, line-editor

- I have some `bindkey` commands in my `.zshrc` file which behave as desired.
- I start `tmux`; the same `.zshrc` is run, including the `bindkey`s but they don't function.
- But then if I manually type them on the command prompt inside tmux, they *do* work again.

I've tried with an empty tmux.conf (`tmux -L test -f /dev/null`) so I know it's not my tmux conf.

- zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
- tmux 3.2a
- Gnome shell (has default TERM=xterm-256color)

It's like tmux is somehow resetting the bind keys *after* running my .zshrc?

After some testing, I found out that if I remove this line from my `.zshrc`, the problem goes away:

```
export EDITOR=`which vim`
```

Why?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing your `.zshrc` (please reduce it to a small file that reproduces the problem) and knowing which key(s) are problematic. Also post the difference in the output of `bindkey` inside and outside tmux, if there's any difference.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks, I tried to reproduce with small-enough-to-share-configs but can't. I bisected my .zshrc (which is massive) and found a quirk around EDITOR env var, see my answer below.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to ask: do you use vi-style key bindings in zsh? From your answer, you don't, except in tmux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like several other popular shells, zsh offers two command line editing modes: Emacs-like (modeless) and Vi-like (with insert and command modes). Unlike other popular shells, [zsh starts up in Vi-like mode](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) if the environment variable `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` contains `vi` when zsh starts up.

You're setting the environment variable `EDITOR` in your `.zshrc`. When you open a terminal and the terminal emulator program starts zsh, `EDITOR` is not set, so zsh starts in Emacs mode. When you start a tmux session from inside that shell, `EDITOR` is set to a string containing `vi` in the environment of tmux, and so it's already set when zsh starts in a tmux window. So, inside tmux windows, zsh runs in Vi-like mode.

In Vi-like operating mode, there are two editing modes: insert and command. Each has its own key bindings, and `bindkey` with no option only applies to insert mode. So your custom bindings don't work in command mode, i.e. after pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>. Most default bindings don't work either.

To avoid this, since you don't appear to want Vi-like mode, explicitly select Emacs-like mode by putting the following command before any other call to `bindkey` in your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -e
```

The real problem is that you're setting `EDITOR` in the wrong place. Generally speaking, don't set environment variables in shell initialization files (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`), because they only take effect in programs that run from that shell. A program started directly from a GUI launcher won't inherit those variables, and so won't call your preferred editor. Instead, set environment variables in a file that is read when your login session starts, such as `~/.profile` (for classical Unix-like sessions, including most X11-based setups).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for explaining that very clearly! I confirm that `bindkey -e` works, and good tip re ~/.profile and env vars (though possibly I'd need a .zprofile too, from what I've read - anyway!) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think this is going to turn out to be a local issue but here's what I've found out:

- My .zshrc contains the line

  ```
  export EDITOR=`which vim`
  ```
- That command results in a filepath to an excutable Neovim AppImage.
- with EDITOR set to this file, things don't work.
- removing the `export` didn't affect things
- coding it so that var is only set if *not* in tmux did not help either.

I'm feeling like there's no point me trying to figure out if this is a bug or in what (tmux? zsh? the autocomplete thing I use? gnome-terminal? neovim? something deep and kernel about app images?)...

But just in case anyone else is affected, as well as the details in the question, I'm using

https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/

and the bindkeys that aren't working (there may be others; not sure)

```
bindkey '\t' menu-select "$terminfo[kcbt]" menu-select
bindkey -M menuselect '\t' menu-complete "$terminfo[kcbt]" reverse-menu-complete
```